# Load Progressive Web App inside iframe

Tags: iframe, web, web-worker, progressive

When loaded a PWA (Progressive Web App) inside a iframe, it will work normal (saving Web Workers, offline availability, etc) or some features will be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I have a PWA that uses an iframe.  It uses some pretty advanced features, including a web-worker (in addition to the service worker) that I implemented long before recently porting it over to a PWA.  All of those features work the same, with the additional benefit of controlled caching of specified resources.  I haven't seen anything in the documentation to suggest otherwise, and can honestly say it works amazing!  So fast to load now, it's in the app drawer, etc., even installs and looks like a normal app on desktop.  My only issue is the soft-keyboard overlaps in fullscreen, but there is a solution, I've seen it work.

My suggestion-- try it.  It's pretty easy to set up.  Test your features.  I am sure you will be impressed.

Comment: I should elaborate that the overlap problem only happens in fullscreen.  If you set 'display' to 'standalone' in your manifest, this doesn't happen.  Also, if your app does not require text input, the soft-keyboard popping is not an issue either way.